# How does x86_64 `syscall` instruction find the desired system call address?

Tags: operating-system, x86-64, system-calls

I'm learning how to implement the system call for my own x86_64 OS project. I know that `syscall` instruction is used for system call, and the underlying operations from https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/syscall.html.

I also noticed that in Linux, the system call number is specified in `%rax`.

What I don't understand is, how does `syscall` find the address of the system call via `%rax`. I assume that the table of system call must be stored somewhere.

I'm looking for more detailed explanation on how `syscall` knows the address of the called system calls.

Comment: I believe the systemcall handler code simply uses `%rax` to index into a global table of function pointers, after doing range checking.

Comment: The syscall instruction just transfers control to a single kernel entry point. Determining the operation to perform is done by the kernel software. Using rax to specify the operation is a software convention. The syscall instruction itself doesn't use rax at all.